# How can I access inline style using React findDomNode function?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I am currently Jest to test React component, component's inline style would be changed according to different props value.

this is an example about what I wanna do:

```
let firstChild = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(renderedComponent, 'div');
    expect(firstChild.getDOMNode().style).toEqual({
      fontSize: '20px'
    });
```

This is the component props:

```
let renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <CircleIcon
        size="small" />
```

And this is the component dom to test with:

```
return (
      <div className="circle-icon" style={boxStyle}>
        <span className={this.props.icon}></span>
      </div>
    );
```

If I can get what is inside boxStyle, I can assert the test result from it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried this? What is your result?

Comment: it works now, just having env problem

Answer (score 5):

actually it works.

usage:

```
firstChild.getDOMNode().style.backgroundColor
```

Comment: don't tell a lie

Comment: : Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.